# Append dataframe inside python function not working?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to append a series of lists to their respective dataframes, but it will not work in a function.  I am not quite sure why it won't work, as I can get it to work outside a function.  However, I want to put it all inside one function so that it is cleaner and can be called later.

```
def append_to_df(list_object):
    i=0
    for list in list_object:
        current_df=df_list[i]
        current_df=current_df.append(list, ignore_index=True)
        #current_df=current_df.drop_duplicates(ignore_index=True, keep=False)
        i+=1
    return None
```

When I call the function, I give it a list of 30 lists that have the data I want to append to 30 dataframes, which I have in the corresponding df_list.  However, after calling the function all the dataframes are still empty.  I imagine this may be a simple conceptual issue with functions, could anyone tell me why the append dataframe works outside of my function but not inside?

Thank you

Comment: have you tried `df_list[i] = df_list[i].append(append(list, ignore_index=True)`?

Comment: That refers to python namespaces, in your function, current_df is re-assigned, and not affect the variable df_list outside the function.

Comment: `df_list[i] = df_list[i].append(alist, ignore_index=True)` could be work, because df_list is in the globle namespace. That means you manipulate `df_list` inside a function, and that works.

Answer (score 0):

Please do not use 'list' which can lead to unknown issues/results:

Use this:

```
def append_to_df(list_object):    
    for i, lst in enumerate(list_object):
        df_list[i] = df_list[i].append(lst, ignore_index=True)
```